# Will Redis get faster with sharding on multiple masters when using no persistence?

Tags: caching, redis, nosql

My tests with standalone (single-threaded) Redis show that load from a number of parallel clients can drive Redis CPU usage to 100% (in my memory cache use case).

Starting it in cluster mode and sharding the content to multiple masters is a possible approach for speeding it up, if persistence is turned on.

I have a configuration without persistence (turned off RDB and AOF). Would starting multiple masters help performance (still using the same cummulative amount of RAM)?

Answer (score 0):

Redis is single-threaded, so the performance of a standalone instance is limited by processing power of a single CPU core and the network bandwidth of a single machine. However, Redis is very very fast. So normally the bottleneck is network bandwidth, unless you run lots of slow commands/lua scripts.

If you deploy Redis cluster on multiple machines, the performance should be improved no matter whether the persistence is turned on or off. Since you have more CPU cores, and more network bandwidth.

If you deploy Redis cluster on a single machine (each node listen on a unique port), the performance might be improved. It depends... If the bottleneck is network bandwidth, it won't be improved. On the other hand, if the bottleneck is CPU processing power, the performance should be improved. So, in this case, you should do some benchmark with your specific data, specific environment, and specific commands/lua scripts.